# OSGI services not loading in Mockito unit tests

Tags: mockito, osgi, inject

I have several service classes that are not loading in Mockito for unit testing. The services are being loaded in classes and Sling models using the @Reference and @Inject annotations.

The case is that I have several services and Sling models that are loading other services using the @Inject or @Reference annotations.

```
public class MyModel{
    @Inject
    SomeService service;
}

public class MyService{
    @Reference
    SomeOtherService service;
}
```

Then when I have a unit test mock the service, the injected services are not loaded. How do I get them loaded into the mock context so that they load are tested as well?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I need to create an instance of the SomeService object and then use the AemContext.registerInjectActivateService() method or the SlingContext.registerInjectActivateService() method to inject them into the context so they are available when the classes being tested load.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the mockito @InjectMocks annotation on your class under test and provide the services to be injected as @Mock.